# I get setmentation fault (core dumped) error in comparing time stamps (C)

Tags: c, timestamp

I am trying to create a function that compare two timestamps, if the first timestamp is earlier than the second one, the function will return -1; if equal, return 0; if later, return 1;

Below is my code, however, it does not work and throws segmentation fault (core dumped) error when I run it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct timeval timevalue;


int compare_time_stamps(timevalue *a, timevalue *b)
{
    int cmp = timercmp(a, b, >);

    if (cmp > 0)
        return 1;            /* a is greater than b */
    else
    {
        cmp = timercmp(a, b, ==);
        if (cmp > 0)
            return 0;    /* a is equal to b */
        else
            return -1;   /* a is less than b */
    }
}

int main()
{
    timevalue *start, *end;

    gettimeofday(start, NULL);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);

    gettimeofday(end, NULL);

    int cmp = compare_time_stamps(start, end);

    printf("comparison result is %d\n", cmp);

    return 0;
}
```

This being said, if I do not start with timevalue *, everything works just fine, see the working code below:

```
typedef struct timeval timevalue;


int compare_time_stamps(timevalue a, timevalue b)
{
    int cmp = timercmp(&a, &b, >);

    if (cmp > 0)
        return 1;            /* a is greater than b */
    else
    {
        cmp = timercmp(&a, &b, ==);
        if (cmp > 0)
            return 0;    /* a is equal to b */
        else
            return -1;   /* a is less than b */
    }
}

int main()
{
    timevalue start, end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    int cmp = compare_time_stamps(start, end);

    printf("the comparison result is %d\n", cmp);

    return 0;
}
```

What makes the difference between these two approaches? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timevalue start, end;
```

when you do this, you are allocating space for the struct `timeval`, which you have called

`typedef struct timeval timevalue;`

so you are actually allocating the space for the two structures in you current stack frame.

when you do `timevalue *start, *end;` you are only allocating two pointers to the struct `timeval` but no memory has been allocated to the struct `timeval` you would have to use `malloc` and allocate space.

```
start = malloc(sizeof(timevalue));
end   = malloc(sizeof(timevalue));
```

also at the end of the function you have to free the malloced memory

```
printf("comparison result is %d\n", cmp);
free(start);
free(end);
return 0;
}
```

in C when you define a pointer(`int *a`) its your job to make sure it points to valid memory. some reading up on pointers should do.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `timevalue*`, `start` is a pointer with no memory allocated to it. It will be having garbage value. Hence you get a segmentation fault.

When you use `timevalue`, the memory is allocated to the `start` variable and the time value is stored there.

Comment: @TonyGW Yes! You should malloc

Answer (score 1):

the macro timbal is a struct like this:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

so you need to allocate memory when you use "*".